# PHP Query Data then Auto rowspan table td if same value data

Tags: php, oracle

How to automatic rowspan `<td>` table when query the data result.

Example :

```
SHP NO | SN
05 | M001
05 | M002
05 | M003
06 | M006
06 | M007
06 | M008
```

to be :

```
SHP NO | SN
       | M001
05     | M002
       | M003
-------------
       | M006
06     | M007
       | M008
```

So if data value same it will auto rowspan the td table.

Here is my query code :

```
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN WHERE TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
$result_q1 = oci_parse($c1, $q1);
oci_execute($result_q1);

while($data = oci_fetch_array)
{
?>
<td></td>

<?php
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, order the result by `shp_no`.
2. While `shp_no` does not change, Save the *rows* to be printed in a `buffer`.
3. If you encounter a different `shp_no`, print the `buffer` and reset it.

Here's how:

```
// Order the results by shp_no
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN WHERE TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY shp_no ASC";
$result_q1 = oci_parse($c1, $q1);
oci_execute($result_q1);

$curr_shpno = NULL; // The current shp_no
$buffer = "";
$count = 0;  // Number of rows of data (used to set the rowspan)
while($data = oci_fetch_array($result_q1))
{
    // If the shp_no has changed, print the rows and reset the buffer
    if($curr_shpno != $data['shp_no']) {
        // Print the rows
        if($count > 0) { // Handle the first shp_no
            // Print the starting <TR> and the <TD> containing the shp_no
            echo "<tr><td rowspan=$count>$curr_shpno</td>";
            echo $buffer;
        }
        $curr_shpno = $data['shp_no'];

        // Reset the buffer, and save the new row (Value of shp_no
        // and the starting <TR> will be added later)
        $buffer = "<td>" . $data['sn'] . "</td></tr>";
        $count = 1;
    }
    else {
        // Save the new row
        $buffer += "<tr><td>" . $data['sn'] . "</td></tr>";
        $count++;
    }
}
```